# Add a line after another line in multiple files

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have opened 100 files like this:

```
[database] 
server=SQL01
db=milli
authentication=auServer

[Misc]
```

Now I need to add the same line like this

```
[database] 
server=SQL01
db=milli
authentication=auServer
username=user1

[Misc]
```

How can I do this, probably some sort of regex?

Comment: Adding a line programatically to a file isn't going to done via Regex -are you looking to do that? Or are you just wanting to find all the places where you need to paste the line in Notepad++?

Comment: I thought I could somehow replace the line authentication=auServer into authentication=auServer then a line feed and then the username=user1 ...  That must be possible no?  authentication is the same in all 100 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this with Notepad++ using the *Find in Files* feature.

Put `authentication=auServer` in the *Find what* text box, `authentication=auServer\r\nusername=user1` in the *Replace with* text box, `*.*` in the *Filters* drop down, `C:\some directory` in the *Directory* drop down, tick the *In all sub-folders* check box, and switch the *Search Mode* to *Extended*.

Then just click *Replace in Files* and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **Find in files** tab on the search dialogue. Make sure **Regular expression** selected. Set the search string to `(db=milli\r\nauthentication=auServer\r\n)(\r\n\[Misc\])` and the replacement to `\1username=user1\r\n\2`. Then click **Replace in files**.

Note that the above will add the line in **ALL** matching places in the files. To specify the files use the **Filter** and **Directory** fields, also make sure that the three tick boxes beneath the **Close** button are correct.

The **Replace in files** should be avoided unless you are confident that it will not destroy your files.